# Way to change width of arrow polyline

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Is there a way i can change the width of the arrow `Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty`? Not the line but the width.
Is there a way i can add an arrow on top of the line?
If not, do you guys have any other suggestions?

[image]